# What is SDRAM 'width'?

Tags: memory

When attempting to install RAM into a system it refuses to boot with an error claiming "SDRAM width of 4 is unsupported, must be 8 or 16".  Various sticks of RAM work just fine on the machine, and the RAM that it won't accept works just fine on other machines.  All of the sticks are DDR3-1333/PC3-10600 and the sticks that don't work vary between 4/8GB sticks (though other 4/8GB sticks work just fine).

I cannot see any real difference between the modules that work and don't work on the machine, so my question is:  "What does SDRAM width refer to, and how can one tell the width of a stick based on the label?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the chips on these DIMMS are probably high-density modules. There is some information on the Wikipedia [DDR SDRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR_SDRAM#High_density_vs_low_density) article.

There is also some more information about at http://1ststop.net/

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is likely going to be labelled as 
DDR3-1600 • 1.5V • 128Meg x 64 •

for instance, this is a 1 GB stick of ram, made up of 64 chips of 128Meg each (128Meg x 64 in the description above)

This information was taken from crucial.com. I wasn't able to find any with the high density option as indicated above, but that may just mean they don't sell them.